# Using JUnit5 without using any build tools like Maven

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, junit, junit5

I am trying to implement JUnit5 via VSCode without using any build tools like Maven. I want to compile the AppTest.java file but it gives me an error of **"error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist."** Here is the current folder structure:

[image]

Here is the AppTest.java code:

[image]

And here is the error when using the **"javac src/AppTest.java"** command:

[image]

As you can see in the bin folder, those classes were autogenerated when I created the .java files. But I want to also generate class files manually using the **"javac command."**

Comment: You need the jars on your classpath both at build time but also runtime.

Comment: Thanks. It successfully compiled already using this command "javac -classpath ./lib/* src/AppTest.java" However, it generated a different .class file compared to the autogenerated one. Thus, JUnit did not work as expected.

Comment: You also need to be in the src folder when compiling.

Comment: It's all good now. The following code worked: "cd src" and then "javac -classpath ../lib/* AppTest.java". Thank you so much!

Comment: Just curious why not just click on the green 'play' button at the left gutter?

Comment: @ShengChen I am working on a project that will check Java programs automatically using this Test file that I created. I want the Test file to be run using a Python script, because just clicking the green 'play' button is too manual, and that would not be good since I'll be checking lots of Java programs.